# Prevent android activity from expanding into navigation bar

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, styles

I am using a NativeActivity with the style `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.FullScreen`. However, the Activity expanded behind the system navigation bar, which is not what I want.

(Black region on the left is due to device cutout, which is what I intended)

I tried to search about this topic and couldn't find posts addressing this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Unintended behavior]

The effect that I intend would be like:
[image: Intended behavior]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function. It will remove only status bar. Call this on `onCreate()`.

```
private fun hideStatusBar() {
    WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window,window.decorView).apply {
        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    }
}
```

To hide only navigation bar,
use `hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())`
To hide both status and navigation bar,
use `hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())`

Additional thing, if you need this in multiple activities, you can create a `BaseActivity` and call this in BaseActivity on create and extend required activities with BaseActivity. So it will work for activities that extend BaseActivity

**Here is Java Equivalent.**

```
private void hideSystemBars() {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(),getWindow().getDecorView());
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    );
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars());
}
```

Hope it helps
[Read more here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive)

Comment: Found out that I just needed to target an API version below 26, and Android will assume my app doesn't support activity expanding behind navigation bar and will make no attempt in doing so. Thanks for the help anyways!